# echo $ANDROID_HOME returns blank (mac os catalina)

Tags: android, macos

[I've followed the instructions here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) to install android studio and the android sdk.

I've added the following lines to ~/.bash_profile, and I've run source ~/.bash_profile.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

The path is correct, I've checked it in Android Studio > Preferences > System Settings > Android SDK.

What is the problem? When I run source ~/.bash_profile, and then echo $ANDROID_HOME, I get some output. But if I close the terminal and restart it, and then I run echo $ANDROID_HOME, I get no output.

If found similar questions here and on other websites, but nothing seems to work. Editing the export lines, directly executing "export ..." in the terminal instead of bash_profile, ... . It all fails to work.

Anyone some tips to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the default shell in Catalina is now zsh, not bash, and zsh presumably doesn't automatically run the .bash_profile.

You could possibly change the shell used in your terminal back to bash by following these instructions: https://support.apple.com/lt-lt/guide/terminal/trml113/mac

Or, you could stay with zsh.  This link: https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh/ has lots of great advice about migrating to zsh.  In particular [part 2](https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh-part-2-configuration-files/) lists the configuration files used by zsh, so you can figure out which one would be the best one to configure ANDROID_HOME and related environment variables.

Comment: You're welcome!  And, welcome to stackoverflow!  If you feel that this answered your question, you may want to mark it as the accepted answer so other stackoverflow users know that this question has been answered successfully.

Comment: When it successful help to someone  ,Dont forget to add up vote ,It is a good humanity habit

Answer (score 9):

Even I am using Mac Catalina 10.15.3. After spending 1 whole week I realized that setting JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME and ANDROID_HOME in **~/.bash_profile** won't work in Catalina and it is uncertain.

I had to move all my environment variables path from ~/.bash_profile to ~/.zshrc file

Below is my ~/.zshrc file

**export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)**

**export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}:$PATH**

## ---------------------------------------------------------

**export M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec**

**export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:$PATH**

## ----------------------------------------------------------

**export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk**

**export PATH=${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:$PATH**

**export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH**

**export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH**

**export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH**

Once you are set. Come out of zshrc by pressing **Esc:wq!**
Close & open the terminal.

> **source ~/.zshrc**
>
> **echo $ANDROID_HOME**

This should display path to ANDROID_HOME

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Even i was also using **Mac Catalina 10.15**

**Fix :**

**Step 1:** Open Terminal

**Step 2:** type the command : **nano .zshrc**

**Step 3:** Add environment variable

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

**Step 4:** Save and quit or (control+o) , Enter + Control+x

**Step 5:** Restart Terminal

Now reverify with **echo $ANDROID_HOME** it will show path /Users/****/Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried closing and re-opening the terminal? I had the same issue and this simple solution was the answer.

Comment: hate to admit, this worked for me as well :D tnx for the reminder sometimes it can really be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

**On Mac Catalina**

I was also facing same issue.

**Fix :**

**Step 1:** Open Terminal

**Step 2:** edit `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zshrc` in my case `vi ~/.zshrc`  and `vi ~/.zprofile`

**Step 3:** Add environment variable

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

**Step 4:** Save and quit

**Step 5:** Restart Terminal

Now reverify with `echo $ANDROID_HOME`  it will show path `/Users/****/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: why do you need to edit `~/.zprofile` isn't it enough to put those values in `./zshenv` ?